# .NET Core 2.1 Windows authentication does not recognise role membership

Tags: c#, .net-core, iis-express

I have followed the tutorials and Stack Overflow questions I can find but still have a problem where I get a 403 Forbidden on a method that is decorated with the [Authorize] attribute.

This is a method that works and proves Google Chrome is passing my Windows credentials to the site which is running in IISExpress during debugging.

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.UserIdentityIsAuthenticated = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
            ViewBag.UserIdentityName = User.Identity.Name;
            ViewBag.UserIsInRoleTechnical = User.IsInRole("ADSecurityGroupOne");
            ViewBag.UserIsInRoleTechnicalPeople = User.IsInRole("ADSecurityGroupOneTwo");

            return View();
        }
```

This is the method that fails with a 403 which is only supposed to show the view, it is not yet linked to any database.

```
    [Authorize(Policy = "AllowedOnly")]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Index(AccountViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
            return View();
    }
```

This is the ConfigureServices method from Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            services.AddOptions();
            ApplicationSettings appSettings = new ApplicationSettings();
            Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationSettings").Bind(appSettings);
            
            services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            services.AddAuthorization(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowedOnly", policy => policy.RequireRole(appSettings.AllowedToMigrate)));
        }
```

I have confirmed that the value of AllowedToMigrate is the same as what is specified in appsettings.json.

```
{
  "ApplicationSettings": {
    "AllowedToMigrate": "ADSecurityGroupOne,ADSecurityGroupTwo"
  },

  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

Why is `[Authorize(Policy = "AllowedOnly"]` failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question because I figured out what I did wrong:

The roles must be supplied as a string array if there's more than one or just a single string if there's only one. I updated the json application settings file and my ApplicationSettings class so that AllowedToMigrate was a string array.

```
{
  "ApplicationSettings": {
    "AllowedToMigrate": [ "ADSecurityGroupOne", "ADSecurityGroupTwo" ]
  },

  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  }
}
```

I also fixed a typo of the role name which was the original problem! So the moral of the story is: Make absolutely sure you are using correctly spelled role names and to always try it with different roles when authorization seems wrong for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to split the `AllowedToMigrate` value into the component roles, not just submit it as one string.

what you actually want to achieve is

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowedOnly", 
    policy => policy.RequireRole("ADSecurityGroupOne", "ADSecurityGroupTwo")));
```

I'm not entirely sure how you would do that from a single config setting tho - probably by creating a new requirement:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: I originally had AllowedToMigrate as a string array but had the same behaviour. If I manually `.RequireRole("ADSecurityGroupOne")` it works and I don't understand why at the moment.